# Increase Scope in Personal account to access Bigquery tables sourced from Google Sheets

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, datagrip, simba

I am using Data Grip with Simba JDBC connection and when I try accessing a Bigquery table sourced from Google Sheets, it gives me an error provided below. This works fine if I run from the Big query UI. Also, if I create a new table with this table info, I am able to query from Data Grip.

I am using my Personal Account for authentication using gcloud auth. Is there a way to increase the scope for my personal account to get necessary permissions to read bigquery tables sourced from google sheets and not using Service Account?

`Error Message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Error code: PERMISSION_DENIED`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access` should be sufficient for adding the necessary scope if you're using user credentials.

See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login for more info, or https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#gcloud for BQ-specific information.

Comment: Thanks for the update .. I tried that but didn't help. Got the same error